# Establish the binary relation R is not a lattice order

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was wondering if anybody could let me know if my solutions are correct and if not some help on correcting them.

Question:

If $\mathbb F$ is the set of all injective functions from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$. Let R be the binary relation such that fRg iff f(x) ≤ g(x) for every x $\in \mathbb Z$. Given that the binary relation R is a partial order.

(a) Show the binary relation R is not a lattice order
(b) Prove or disprove: If f and g are two distinct functions in $\mathbb F$ and are surjective, then f and g are incomparable with respect to the partial order R.

My attempt:

(a) For R to be a lattice order, for any two elements f,g  $\in \mathbb F$, f, and g have a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound. So to show R is not a lattice order I need to give a counterexample. So I said let f(x) = x and g(x) = x-1, then both h(x) = 2x and p(x) = x+1 are upper bounds for f and g. However, h and p are incomparable so f and g do not have a least upper bound.

(b) Let f(x) = x and g(x) = x+1 , so f and g are both injective and surjective and f(x) ≤ g(x) $ \forall x \in \mathbb Z$ so fRg so they are comparable with respect to R, thus disproving the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument in (b) is correct.

In (a), however, $h(x)=2x$ is not an upper bound for $f$ or $g$, since it lies above $f$ for positive $x$ and below $f$ for negative $x$.

Instead, consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$ except $g(0)=1$ and $g(1)=0$, and let $h$ be an upper bound for $\{f,g\}$. Then $h'$ with $h'(x)=h(x)$ except $h'(0)=h(1)$ and $h'(1)=h(0)$ is also an upper bound, and it is incomparable to $h$.